# Nonnormal subgroup of $Q_8 \times Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, direct-product

This problem from book  Dummit and Foote "Abstract algebra":

> Exhibit nonnormal subgroup of $Q_8 \times Z_4.$

Let $q  \in Q_8$ and $z \in Z_4.$ Let $N$ be nonnormal subgroup of $Q_8 \times Z_4 $. Then  there exist $g \in Q_8 \times Z_4$  and  $n=(q_n,z_n) \in N$ such that $g^{-1}n g = (q^{-1},z^{-1}) (q_n,z_n) (q,z)=(q^{-1}q_nq,z^{-1}z_nz) \notin N.$ 
In the other hand every subgroup of $Q_8$ and every subgroup of $Q_8$ are normal.

I  get tripped up on this problem!

Comment: Note that $z^{-1}z_nz=z_n$ since $Z_4$ is abelian. So you're looking for a subgroup that contains some element $(a,b)$ but misses some element $(c,b)$ where $c$ is conjugate to $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $N = \langle (i,1)\rangle$ which is cyclic of order $4$:

$(i,1)^2 = (-1,2)\\(i,1)^3 = (-i,3)\\(i,1)^4 = (1,0).$

Now $(j,0)(i,1)(j,0)^{-1} = (jij^{-1},0+1-0) = (ji(-j),1)$

$= ((-k)(-j),1) = (kj,1) = (-i,1) \not\in N$.

Comment: This is amazing, but what was your motivation? Seems totally out of the blue.

Answer (score 7):

I'll use [Goursat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat's_lemma) to give a slightly more technical and methodical answer, with hopes that this introduces techniques that can generalize to other similar situations. Goursat's lemma characterizes all subgroups of a direct product and then we can ask which subgroups can possibly be normal in the case of $Q_8 \times Z_4$.

The statement of the lemma is that for groups $G, H$, the set of *all* subgroups of $G \times H$ is in bijective correspondence with the set of tuples $(G_1, H_1, N, M, \varphi)$, where $N \trianglelefteq G_1 \leq G, M \trianglelefteq H_1 \leq H$, and

\begin{align}
\varphi: G_1/N \rightarrow H_1/M
\end{align}

is an isomorphism. To use this in practice, the point is that any $K \leq G \times H$ is given by

\begin{align}
K_{\varphi} = \{(g,h) \,|\, g \in G_1, h \in H_1, \varphi(gN) = hM \}
\end{align}

for each $\varphi$ satisfying the isomorphism condition above (see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product?rq=1) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212219/is-there-another-name-for-goursats-lemma-on-subgroups-of-a-direct-product-of-gr/3212436#3212436) for more info on Goursat's lemma).

---

Now let's apply Goursat's lemma in the case of $Q_8 \times Z_4$. We first consider all possible subgroups of $Q_8$ and $Z_4$ and their respective normal subgroups, and then find all cases where we have $G_1/N \cong H_1/M$, as in the statement of the lemma.

\begin{align}
\text{Subgroups of } Q_8 &: Q_8, Z_4, Z_2, 1\\
\text{Subgroups of } Z_4 &: Z_4, Z_2, 1
\end{align}

Let's consider what happens when we have trivial quotient groups (for example, $G_1 = Q_8, N = Q_8, H_1 = Z_4, M = Z_4$ and then we obtain $Q_8/Q_8 \cong 1 \cong Z_4/Z_4$). In this case, following the statement of Goursat's lemma above, we only have a single isomorphism $\varphi$ to the trivial group. Then this corresponds to $K_{\varphi} \leq G \times H$ as

\begin{align}
K_{\varphi} = \{(g,h)\,|\,g\in G_1, h \in H_1\}
\end{align}

because there is only a single coset in $Q_8/Q_8$ and in $Z_4/Z_4$, and so every $g \in Q_8 = G_1$ satisfies the condition $\varphi(g Q_8) = h Z_4$ for every $h \in Z_4 = H_1$.

In other words, the quotient groups are trivial if and only if $K_{\varphi}$ is the direct product of a subgroup of $G$ and a subgroup of $H$. Since every subgroup of $Q_8$ and $Z_4$ is normal, every $G_1 \times H_1 \trianglelefteq G \times H$.

**Next**, it's quite quick to write all possible nontrivial quotient groups such that $G_1/N \cong H_1/M$ (noting that every subgroup of both $Q_8$ and $Z_4$ is normal):

\begin{align}
G_1/N &\cong X \cong H_1/M\\ \hline
Q_8/Z_4 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_4/Z_2\\
Q_8/Z_4 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_2/1 \\
Z_4/Z_2 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_4/Z_2 \\
Z_4/Z_2 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_2/1 \\
Z_4/1 &\cong Z_4 \cong Z_4/1 \\
Z_2/1 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_4/Z_2 \\
Z_2/1 &\cong Z_2 \cong Z_2/1 \\
\end{align}

(notice $Q_8/Z_2$ can't appear in the list, because it is the Klein four-group and so can't be isomorphic to any quotient of $Z_4$). The condition for $K_{\varphi}$ to be normal in $G \times H$ is

\begin{align}
(x g x^{-1}, y h y^{-1}) \in K_{\varphi},\quad 
\forall\, (x,y) \in Q_8 \times Z_4, (g,h) \in K_{\varphi}
\end{align}

$Z_4$ is abelian and so this reduces to

\begin{align}
(x g x^{-1}, h) \in K_{\varphi},\quad 
\forall\, (x,y) \in Q_8 \times Z_4, (g,h) \in K_{\varphi}
\end{align}

The condition $(x g x^{-1}, h) \in K_{\varphi}$ means that $\varphi(x g x^{-1} N) = h M = \varphi(g N)$. In other words, $x g x^{-1}$ needs to be in the same coset as $g$, or equivalently $x g x^{-1} g^{-1} \in N$. It's convenient to use the notation of the [group commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup):

\begin{align}
[x,g] \in N, \quad \forall g \in G_1, \forall x \in G = Q_8
\end{align}

Now we refer to our list above of nontrivial quotients and check when it's possible for $[x,g] \in N$. It's useful to check the commutator subgroup (group generated by all commutators) of $Q_8$, and we find that it is $Z_2$. So in every quotient of the form $G_1/Z_4$ or $G_1/Z_2$ in the list above, any commutator of $[x,g], \, g \in G_1, x \in Q_8$ will be in $Z_2 \leq N$ for these groups. Altogether, all of these subgroups are normal in $Q_8 \times Z_4$.

We could have checked the commutator subgroup and used this observation earlier when we were considering trivial quotients, but it was useful to show that case on its own, to get a feel for what Goursat's lemma is actually saying and to prepare for other similar questions where possibly things don't line up so nicely.

**Lastly,** according to our analysis, the only subgroups that can possibly fail to be normal in $Q_8 \times Z_4$ are those corresponding to the $G_1/N$ quotients $Z_4/1$ or $Z_2/1$. These are resolved as follows:

- $Z_2$ is the center of $Q_8$ and so the commutators $[x,g], \, g \in Z_2, x \in Q_8$ will all lie in the trivial group $1$, which corresponds to $N$ for this case. So the subgroups corresponding to $Z_2/1$ are all normal in $Q_8 \times Z_4$.
- The groups corresponding to $Z_4/1$ are not normal if and only if we can find $[x,g] = -1 \iff xg = -gx$ (we know that the commutators have to be -1 or 1 because $Z_2$ is the commutator subgroup of $Q_8$, and if they are always 1, then they lie in $N = 1$ and the corresponding groups are normal). Certainly $xg = -gx$ occurs, for example $ij = -ji$.

Altogether, we find that $K \not\trianglelefteq Q_8 \times Z_4$ if and only if $K$ corresponds to $G_1/N = Z_4/1$. One can check that one such subgroup is $\{(1,0),(i,1),(-1,2),(-i,3)\}$ as was found in David Wheeler's answer.