# Finding subgroups of $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$. Why can't there be more?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My solution consists of taking direct products of both $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ and then their direct product. Apart from that I took $\langle 2,0\rangle, \langle 2,1\rangle, \langle 1,1\rangle$ as subgroup generators and generated more subgroups by brute force.

This doesn't seem an efficient method. How do I know when I have to stop? This is a small question but in the context of bigger questions, how do I know when I have found all the subgroups.

Comment: This is a Big Question. Are you interested in the case of finite abelian groups, or finite groups in general, or groups in general? In the last case, there really is no answer — you abstractly _can't_ necessarily enumerate 'all' the subgroups of even a countable group.

Comment: If you're just interested in this specific example, one way to approach this problem is by looking at all of the isomorphism class of groups of order less than $8$. It turns out there are only $11$ of these classes, and you can further constrain this down to just $7$ using Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: I was starting off by just focussing on this example. And yes I have realized,  there is no way to know for general cases.

Comment: @Alzebrian Are you interested in the subgroups up to isomorphism, i.e. the structure of the subgroups, or what each subgroup is actually composed of, i.e. the elements?

Comment: It's composition more so as of now.

Answer (score 7):

The magic words are “Goursat’s Lemma” (or “subdirect products”), but I don’t think you’ll find it less “work intensive”. It is a description of *all* subgroups of a direct product $G\times H$.

For general comments see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212219/is-there-another-name-for-goursats-lemma-on-subgroups-of-a-direct-product-of-gr); for an example of an application see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515809/two-applications-of-goursats-lemma-in-group-theory).

Basically, if $G$ and $H$ are groups, then the subgroups of $G\times H$ correspond to the following five pieces of information:

1. A subgroup $A$ of $G$;
2. A normal subgroup $N$ of $A$;
3. A subgroup $B$ of $H$;
4. A normal subgroup $K$ of $B$;
5. An isomorphism $f\colon (A/N)\to (B/K)$.

The 5-tuple $(A,N,B,K,f)$ then corresponds to the subgroup
$$S(A,N,B,K,f) = \{(g,h)\in A\times B\mid f(gN)=hK\}.$$

That these are all subgroups is fairly easy to verify; Goursat’s Lemma is the proof that every subgroup is of this form.

If you understand $G$ and $H$ very well, then this may lead to a less work-intensive process; but if not, then you end up having to list all subgroups of $G$ and their quotients, and all subgroups of $H$ and *their* quotients, and then all possible isomorphisms between pairs of such quotients.

For the example here it is relatively straightforward, but you may find it just as work-intensive as your original method.

The possible quotients-of-subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ itself (with $B=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $K=\{0\}$), and the trivial group (with either $B=K=\mathbb{Z}_2$, or $B=K=\{0\}$). The possible quotients-of-subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (with $A=\mathbb{Z}_4$, $N=\{0\}$), $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (with $A=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $N=\langle 2\rangle$; and with $A=\langle 2\rangle$ and $N=\{0\}$); and the trivial group (with $A=N=\mathbb{Z}_4$, $A=N=\langle 2\rangle$, and $A=N=\{0\}$). So you get the following subgroups, when we pair the $\mathbb{Z}_2$s together, and when we pair the trivial groups together:

1. When $A=\mathbb{Z}_4$, $N=\langle 2\rangle$, $B=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $K=\{0\}$, the subgroup consists or $(1,1)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,1)$, and $(0,0)$; i.e., $\langle (1,1)\rangle$.
2. When $A=\langle 2\rangle$, $N=\{0\}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $K=\{0\}$, the subgroup consists of $(2,1)$ and $(0,0)$; i.e., $\langle (2,1)\rangle$.
3. When $A=N=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $B=K=\mathbb{Z}_2$, you get $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.
4. When $A=N=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $B=K=\{0\}$, you get $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\{0\}$.
5. When $A=N=\langle 2\rangle$ and $B=K=\mathbb{Z}_2$, you get the $\langle 2\rangle\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.
6. When $A=N=\langle 2\rangle$ and $B=K=\{0\}$, you get $\langle 2\rangle\times\{0\}$.
7. When $A=N=\{0\}$ and $B=K=\mathbb{Z}_2$ you get $\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.
8. When $A=N=\{0\}$ and $B=K=\{0\}$ you get $\{0\}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: Arturo Magidin, is your answer relevant to this question [Correspondence theorem: Subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$ that contain $2\mathbb Z \times 4\mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283337/correspondence-theorem-subgroups-of-mathbb-z2-that-contain-2-mathbb-z-tim) please?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon: Sure, you can use Goursat's Lemma to describe the subgroups of the quotient (which is a direct product). No, I won't spell it out either here or there. And I'm not overly fond of getting notifications on old answers that are essentially "Hey, could you take a look at this *other*, possibly related, post?"