# Is this relationship on subcartesian products of quotient groups over the free group correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, universal-algebra

I am trying to check if the following relationship is correct. Let $F$ be a free group over some set $X$. Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ be epimorphisms from $F$ to groups $H_1, H_2, ..., H_n$ respectively. Let $K_1, K_2, ..., K_n$ be the kernels of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ respectively. It follows that $K_1, K_2, ..., K_n$ are all normal.

Now, let $K= \bigcap K_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ (i.e. the normal group formed from the intersection of the kernels). We can now form the quotient $F/K$.

Is it true that $F/K$ is isomorphic to a subcartesian product of $F/K_1,F/K_2,...,F/K_n$ ? How could I show it ?

I want to check if this is correct since this would then mean that $F/K$ is also isomorphic to a subcartesian product of $H_1,H_2,...,H_n$ ...

(For context over this question, am trying to understand a proof for Birkhoff's variety theorem which uses the above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** as pointed out in the comments, "subcartesian product" has a formal meaning and is *not* the same as a cartesian product of subgroups.

Some thoughts which I found too long for a comment:

The maps $\alpha_i$ define a map

$$
f \colon t \in F \mapsto (\alpha_1(t),\ldots, \alpha_n(t)) \in H_1 \times \cdots \times H_n
$$

Its kernel consists of the $t \in F$ for which $\alpha_i(t) = 1$ for all $i$ simultaneously, i.e. $K = \cap_i K_i$. Hence

$$
F/K \simeq \mathbf{im} f \leq H_1 \times \cdots \times H_n.
$$

We have not used that each $\alpha_i$ is epi nor the fact that $F$ is free. In general, the image of $f$ need not be a cartesian product of subgroups, even with these hypotheses (e.g. if $F = \Bbb Z$, $n = 2$, and $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = id$, then $f$ is the diagonal map $\Delta \colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z^2$).

It may be that $F/K$ is still isomorphic to some cartesian product through some other morphism.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your example. One has $\Delta(f) = \{(n,n) \mid n \in {\Bbb Z}\}$. Isn't it a subgroup of ${\Bbb Z}^2$ which maps onto ${\Bbb Z}$ under the two projections?

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta(Id)$? Yes, indeed. I didn't understand your confusion, care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\Delta({\Bbb Z})$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand what the confusion is/where it stems from

Comment: Why do you say that the image of $f$ is not a subcartesian product?

Comment: In that case, the diagonal is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, my point is that that need not be the case in general. A subgroup of $H \times G$ need not be of the the form $H' \times G'$ with $H \leq H', G \leq G'$. The diagonal in $\mathbb Z^2$ is such an example: there are no $m\mathbb Z, n \mathbb Z$ such that $\Delta(\mathbb Z) = m \mathbb Z \times n\mathbb Z$. As the posts says, it may still be that the image of $f$ is *isomorphic* to some cartesian product.

Comment: I am afraid that your definition of a [subcartesian product](https://planetmath.org/subdirectproductofgroups) is not right.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I was unaware that this had a formal meaning. Fixed to convey what I originally meant! Thanks. I can also see that the question meant something different... Also, what's the intuition for this? I would expect a subcartesian product to be, in general, a non-trivial product of groups in of itself. But the definition suggests otherwise, I think

Comment: @guidoar: Subdirect products are an important tool when dealing with decompositions of algebras in general. In the case of products of two groups, you may be familiar with [Goursat's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212219/is-there-another-name-for-goursats-lemma-on-subgroups-of-a-direct-product-of-gr/3212436#3212436) which uses subdirect products to describe all subgroups of a product $G\times H$.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the link Arturo, I will give it a read; I did not know about Goursat's Lemma (I think the only result in that direction that I can recall is that if $G \times H$ is finite with factors of coprime order then its subgroups are actually product of subgroups).

Comment: @guidoar: That would follow from Goursat's Lemma, since in that case the isomorphisms that can occur are trivial.

Comment: @guidoar: See, e.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515809/two-applications-of-goursats-lemma-in-group-theory/3516245#3516245).

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a subdirect product of $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$  is a subgroup $M\leq \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ such that $\pi_j(M)=G_j$ for all $j\in I$.

In general, if $G$ is a group, $\{H_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of groups, and $f_i\colon G\to H_i$ are morphisms, then we obtain an induced homomorphism
$$f\colon G\to \prod_{i\in I}H_i$$
by the universal property of the product. This map has the property that for each $i\in I$, $\pi_i\circ f = f_i$.  If $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, you can "visualize" $f$ as the map $f(g) = (f_1(g),\ldots,f_n(g))$.

In this case, the image of $f$ is always a subdirect product of the family $\{f_i(G)\}_{i\in I}$.

Indeed, given $h_i\in f_i(G)$, we know there exists $g\in G$ such that $f_i(g)=h_i$. Then $\pi_i(f(g)) = f_i(g) = h_i$ by definition, so there exists an element in $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ that has $i$th coordinate equal to $h_i$. This proves that $f(G)$ is a subdirect product of $\{f_i(G)\}_{i\in I} = \{\mathrm{Im}(f_i)\}_{i\in I}$.

In your situation, $G=F$ is a free group and the maps $\alpha_i$ are surjective (I avoid "epimorphism" because there are varieties of groups where you have nonsurjective epimorphisms; of course, [in the category of all groups epimorphisms are surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443049/show-that-f-is-an-epimorphism-of-groups-if-and-only-if-f-is-surjective-as-a/3608316#3608316), but I prefer not to conflate the two). So certainly the map $F\to H_1\times\cdots\times H_n$ has image that is a subdirect product. The only thing remaining is to verify that the morphism factors through $K$, but that follows because the kernel of the universal map $\alpha\colon F\to H_1\times\cdots\times H_n$ is precisely the intersection of the kernels of the maps $\alpha_i$, which is $K$.