# Let $G$ be finite, non-trivial. Let $K$ be a compact Lie group s.t. if $J\le G\times K$, then $J=H\times L$ for $H\le G, L\le K$. Is $K$ finite?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, compactness

Let $G$ be a finite, non-trivial group and let $K$ be a compact Lie group such that each subgroup of $G\times K$ is of the form $H\times L$ for some subgroups $H\subset G$ and $L\subset K$. Is it true that then $K$ is also finite?

I tried in vain to find a counterexample, and I guess that the claim is true, but I do not know how to prove it. The answers to the question [When must the subgroup of a product be the product of subgroups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212538/when-must-the-subgroup-of-a-product-be-the-product-of-subgroups) come quite close to my problem, but I am not sure how to use them to prove the above statement.

Comment: In what way do the linked answers fall short? It seems that it would suffice to show that every compact torsion Lie group is finite.

Comment: You are right. But why is every compact tosrion Lie group finite? Does this follow from the fact that any infinite compact Lie group contains a maximal torus?

Comment: It certainly seems so, since tori always contain non-torsion points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case $K$ is finite.

Indeed, if $K_0$ is a connected component of $1$, then by the definition of Lie group $K_0$ is an open normal subgroup of $K$. Since the factor group $K/K_0$ is discrete and compact, it is finite.

If $K_0\neq\{1\}$, then $K_0$ contains a connected abelian compact subgroup $A$ (e.g. the image of a one-dimensional subalgebra from the Lie algebra of group $K_0$ under exponential mapping). Since $A\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ there is an element of order $p$ in $A$ for any prime $p$. If $a\in G$ and $b\in A$ are elements of order $p$ for a prime $p$, then the diagonal of the subgroup $\operatorname{gr}(a)\times\operatorname{gr}(b)$ has order $p$ and hence cannot be represented as a direct product of non-trivial subgroups.

It follows that $K_0=\{1\}$ and the group $K$ is finite.