# Must a subgroup of $H\times K$ be the direct product of two subgroups of $H$ and $K$ respectively

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have some doubt in the following statement: Let $H$ and $K$ be two ***finite*** Groups and let $G$ denote their direct product. If $S＜G$ , then does $S$ must be of the form $H'\times K'$ for some subgroups $H'$ and $K'$ of $H$ and $K$ respectively?

This is my idea: for all $(h, k)\in S$ , we must have
$$
(h_1, k_1)(h_2, k_2)^{-1}=(h_1h_2^{-1}, k_1k_2^{-1})\in S\ , 
$$
as desired.

Comment: Think of the case $H = K = \mathbf{Z}/2$.

Comment: No, this is not true, and your argument does not say anything about whether it's true or not. See Goursat's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma

Comment: If $|H|$ and $|K|$ are not relatively prime, then just find elements $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ of the same order, and look at $\langle (h,k)\rangle$.The result holds for finite groups if and only if $\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$.

Comment: @ronno Thanks for your example, I have realized it.

Comment: Yes, my argument just show that the first component forms a subgroup of $H$ and the second one forms a subgroup of $K$ , but not necessarily the direct product of these two subgroups. Thanks. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Thanks for giving the general case of this problem. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is that any proof of your latter statement, I need to use this result, thanks.

Comment: @DianWei https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4212538/742