# Group theory: $l(G \times H) = l(G) + l(H)$ and $fact(G \times H) = fact(G) \cup fact(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups then proof that $l(G \times H) = l(G) + l(H)$ and $fact(G \times H) = fact(G) \cup fact(H)$. Where $l$ is the length of any of its composition series and $fact$ are the factors of any of its composition series.

I don't really see how I would build a composition series for the product.

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product

Comment: I found the answer here http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~tkenney/3030/2012/solutions13.pdf i'll write it with more time