# Product of ramification groups: Is $G_i= H_i H'_i$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of local fields with Galois group $G$.
Suppose we have two linear disjoint Galois subextensions $E/K$ and $E'/K$ of $L/K$ with $EE'=L$.
Let $H=G(L/E)$ and $H'=G(L/E')$.
Then we get $G=H H'$.

Now consider the higher ramification groups $G_{i}= \{ \sigma \in G \mid v_L(\sigma x -x)\geq i+1\}$ where $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[x]$. $H_i$ and $H'_i$ are defined similarly.

My question: Is it true that $G_i= H_i H'_i$?

I was neither able to prove it nor to construct an example where it does not hold. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Let $r(\sigma,E) = \inf \{ v_L(\sigma(a)-a) - v(a), a \in E\}$ then don't we have $r(\sigma,L) = \min(r(\sigma,E),r(\sigma,E'))$

Comment: If this were true, then the compositum of two totally ramified extensions would be totally ramified, but  this is false, e.g. $K = \mathbf{Q}_2$, $E = \mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$ and $E' = \mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt{-6})$.

Comment: S4KUL, observe that in user687721's example neither $L/E$ nor $L/E'$ is ramified.

Comment: [A somewhat related mistaken belief](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084878/11619).

Comment: I understand the example, thanks! Is there also an example if $L/K$ is supposed to be totally ramified?