# Let $A'$ be subgroup of $A$ and $B'$ be subgroup of $B$. What can we say if $A'/B' \cong A/B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say $A'$ is subgroup of $A$ and $B'$ is subgroup of $B$ such that the quotient group $\frac{A'}{B'}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{A}{B}$. Does this imply any additional relationship between $A$ and $A'$ or $B$ and $B'$?

I can't seem to think of any, so help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [Goursat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) might be of interest to you

Comment: [The answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/488222/350022) writes out explicitly a characterization of subgroups of a direct product using Goursat's lemma. It involves the sort of data you have in your situation.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the close votes here. The question seems to be asked out of interest - it certainly is unlikely to be an exam question, and likely to be of interest to others in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Already a trivial case like $A=B$ and $A'=B'$ being subgroups gives
$A/B=A'/B'=1$, but we don't have any relationship between $A$ and $A'$, except for the assumption that $A'$ is a subgroup of $A$.

For examples with nontrivial quotient group consider $A=\Bbb Z$ and $B=2\Bbb Z$, with $A'=2\Bbb Z$ and $B'=4\Bbb Z$. Then
$$
A'/B'=2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=A/B.
$$

Comment: Please refresh you understanding about the Enforcement of Quality Standards.  First you answer a dupe, and then answer a PSQ, and .....  in one day!

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I understand (and have deleted my answer at the dupe). This question, however, deserves an answer, I believe.