# Finite subgroups of O(3)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, orthogonal-matrices

My question is the following: What are the finite subgroups of O(3), the group of linear isometries?

I managed to find a lot of good references describing the finite subgoups of SO(3) (only direct isometries), but not O(3). [This pdf for instance.](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2020/REUPapers/Bui,An.pdf)

Can someone please help me find a reference on the subject?

Comment: SO$(3)$ is an index $2$ subgroup of O$(3)$, and indeed O$(3)$ is a semi-direct product of SO$(3)$ with any order $2$ subgroup generated by a reflection. Since you know the finite subgroups of O$(3)$, this information above should make it easy - simply throw reflections into the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $O(3)$ is isomorphic to $SO(3)\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Understanding the subgroups of products of groups is explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product) and the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is very simple to work with.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated! :-)