# Closed subgroup of units of p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers

I understood that all closed subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$, and multiplicative group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{Z}_p$

Then, why the closed subgroup of this unit group is of form
$A\times p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $A$ is subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$?

I don’t have any idea how to find(classify) all closed subgroup of multiplicative group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_p
$
Why they must be of form $A\times p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$? Aren’t there any other possibilities?

Comment: I´m sorry if I edited wrongly. Did you mean $A\times p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$ in line 4 instead of  $A\times \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: I corrected that point. Thank you

Comment: I am not $100 \%$ sure, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map) might be related, since $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be compact.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial besides.

Comment: [This paper](https://intapi.sciendo.com/pdf/10.1515/tmmp-2015-0039) scetches the idea of a proof of Goursat´s lemma, which is the characterization of subgroups of a product, that is used in the answer by Tobias Kildetoft mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer why the subgroups are direct products of subgroups but only which of those (latter) can occur.To see why all subgroups must be direct products of subgroups see the comment by @Torsten Schoeneberg below and in the linked post Tobias Kildetoft´s answer. It follows all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ are  of the form $$A\times B$$
where $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ as a topological space is compact, the projection map
$$\pi:\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$$ is closed  and thus $B$ must be closed in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ whenever $A\times B$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ and thus $B=0$ or $B=p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: My question is, why they are of form A product B?

Comment: All points (x,y) where x=y form a subgroup of Euclidean plane(which is product of two real lines), but this set is definitely not a product of two subsets of real line. Subgroup of direct product need not be a direct product

Comment: You are right, I see Your point. I will think about it and write later. I also edited my answer, which is not an answer to Your crucial question.

Comment: To amend the missing step: Subgroups of direct products are described in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485512/96384. In this case, it is obvious that the only chance to get an iso from a subquotient of $\mathbb Z/(p-1)$ to a subquotient of $\mathbb Z_p$ (all of whose finite subquotients have order a power of $p$) is when both subquotients are trivial, i.e. in the notation of that answer, $G_1=G_2$ and $H_1=H_2$. It follows that here, subgroups of the direct product are direct products of subgroups.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank You very much! The bijection between subgroups and 5-tuples yielding isomorphisms between subquotients is something I would have  never come up with, but indeed it is obvious here that the subquotients must be trivial.